# How to add a context menu item in devtools > network panel?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I do an Extension for Google Chrome and have some problems with it. I need to add a contextMenu item to devtool > network

[image]

How can I do it? I just found instructions only how to add an easy contextMenu, not in devtool (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contextMenus#method-create).

Comment: It's not possible to modify that context menu. BTW why have you hidden the screenshot again after I edited the question to make it visible?

Comment: @wOxxOm - the `!` was possibly removed by the validation step that prevents image embedding for < 15 rep users. Its fixed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible, Chrome does not provide APIs to extend the context menu of Network tab of DevTools, or anything else in the Network tab.

As an alternative, you can [add your own tab to Dev Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools) and use [`chrome.devtools.network`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools_network) to populate your own UI.